# LAN distributed file system

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization

I have several computers at home (windows and linux), not to mention my android phone.  I also have a music library, some commonly useful files, etc.  I end up with copies of files scattered irregularly across multiple devices - and sometimes multiple places on one device.

I'm tempted to write a networked filesystem to make the files available to all the devices, without keeping copies on all computers.  But there are SO many other things to be doing, and surely someone has written something similar!  I've looked briefly at LizardFS, MinIO, JuiceFS, etc., but it's hard to tell exactly how they work without spending a lot of time trying to install them, and most seem geared towards cloud/server uses, anyway.

Here's the kind of system I'd envision.

You can create a virtual drive, shared across your network.  When you put a file in it, it's stored by hash (for deduplication etc.), and the other nodes are informed of the tree change - but not sent the file, yet.  (Optional: ensure each file is stored on at least N nodes at any time.)  (Optimization: nodes can delete old files if running low on space AND other nodes have a copy.)  When the user tries to open a file that isn't cached locally, it's streamed from another node (and also cached locally).  Ideally cross-platform.

Nice-to-haves: version history, the ability to connect two networks and copy files from one drive to another, maybe securely exposing filesystem on external IP?  Not sure how to deal with file searches.

[Resilio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/platforms/desktop/) looks kinda right, at first glance, but I get the impression it keeps copies on all devices.

[Perkeep](https://perkeep.org) looks even closer.  Not sure if it permits all nodes to have caches.  As before, hard to tell without setting up a server and messing with it for like three hours.

Anybody know of a close fit to my "specs", or whether one of the above does do the trick?

Comment: 2*WIkipedia: [AFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System)? [IPFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System)?

Comment: @knb AFS looks promising; I'll look into it; thanks

Comment: my undergrad University TU-Chemnitz has [AFS in production](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/urz/storage/afs/), at scale, since circa 1995. You can translate those pages to German on demand. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: @knb Ah; thanks